# How to use clang/llvm with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, llvm, clang

Is it possible to use [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) with [Eclipse CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) and if so, how is it configured to actually make it work?

Comment: I added an answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973325/how-do-i-setup-a-clang-toolchain-in-eclipse-on-windows/33289129#33289129

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I am the main author of the (only) LLVM plug-in for Eclipse CDT. It is still in development so might not be suitable for production environment yet. However feel free to test it to find out if it is suitable for your needs.

https://github.com/TuononenP/llvm4eclipsecdt

**UPDATE**
The latest version is available via official Eclipse update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

It is under Programming Languages and is named "C/C++ LLVM-Family Compiler Build Support".

Comment: I will appreciate any feedback so that I can improve it.

Comment: Petri Tuononen, is there any progress in development?

Comment: I am sorry to inform that I have not had time lately to do any improvements so it is on hold at the moment. Let's see if I have some time after Christmas.

Comment: ^ Indeed, the plugin supports Cygwin and MinGW.

Comment: I have an autotools-managed project in Eclipse. Compilation works after overriding `CXX` flag, but syntax highlighting in CDT does not work, since it tries to use GCC 4.2 (included in Xcode). You can see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086835/using-clang-for-code-analysis-in-an-autotools-project-in-eclipse) for more details. Can your plugin be used so that syntax highlighting in CDT uses Clang, and therefore it supports C++11?

Comment: @ Petri Tuononen do you any plan for clang3.5 ?

Comment: The plugin only works up to version 3.2.  There are is now llc, lld, and clang++ commands that take different options.

Comment: The original plugin is now deprecated but the updated version is now in official Eclipse update site (link in answer) and I suppose it should work with new Clang versions, but haven't tested.

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin appears to no longer be supported - pity

Answer (score 25):

Here is the LLVM plugin for CDT http://code.google.com/p/llvm4eclipsecdt/

And here ↑↑↑↑ is its author, Petri Tuononen. Thank you, Petri!