# C++ using eclipse juno on a mac - "binary not found"

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gcc

Okay so I've been to every corner of the internet and cannot solve this. I had a java installation on eclipse juno and I installed the CDT plugin to develop C++ applications with it. I get the binary not found error, so I installed XCode and the command line tools and still cannot run my applications. I have no idea what else to try. I would manually point eclipse to the gcc compiler but I can't figure out where XCode installs it.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, recent versions of XCode come with Clang/LLVM as default instead of gcc, so you might be looking for a compiler that's not installed on your system!

If you want to use gcc, you have to install it first.  I personally recommend using some package manager, such as [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).  At that point, make sure gcc is in your path, or edit your Eclipse settings and you're good to go.

The other option is to stick with Clang.  You can refer to [this SO question about setting up Eclipse to use Clang/LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802448/how-to-use-clang-llvm-with-eclipse-cdt).  You'll have to use the LLVM plugin for Eclipse CDT.