# Cannot build executable from eclipse + CDT when using llvm + clang

Tags: c, eclipse, clang, llvm, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use Eclipse Luna + CDT + Linux + clang 3.6. 
I'm not able to let eclipse + clang build native executable file. There is no option to select "executable" in Project -> Properties -> c\c++ build -> Settings -> Build Artifact -> Artifact type. There is only "Static library" is shown. 
Could please somebody advise?

Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to ask if you found a solution you could post.  I can confirm this is an issue in C++ projects in Windows using the LLVM/Clang Toolchain for Eclipse Luna, (+ CDT and MinGW).  The GUI provides some static library flags, but not for executables.  The settings have to provided manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use clang/llvm with Eclipse CDT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802448/how-to-use-clang-llvm-with-eclipse-cdt)